# Solving $a \cos(x) + \sin(x) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I'd like to know if it is possible to solve the following equation for $x$:

$a\cos(x) + \sin(x) = 0$

Where $a$ is a constant. At first, I've used the small angle approximation, and it was OK, however, now I'm trying to solve the equation without using such approximation.

Comment: Hint : Divide by $\cos(x)$. Think about why this cannot be $0$ , if $x$ is a solution.

Comment: If you re-arrange the equation, you will have $ \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \tan(x) = - a $, therefore $  x = - \tan^{-1} a $.  The other solution is obtained by adding  $\pi$ to this.

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea This is more or less the full solution. Unfortunately, the author has no chance anymore to finish the exercise alone.

Comment: That's unfortunate,  may be he has better luck with similar questions or totally different questions.

Comment: Thanks @Calmdownandhavesometea for your help.

Comment: $a\cos(x)+\sin(x)=0\Rightarrow \dfrac{a\cos(x)+\sin(x)}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}=0$. There is an angle $\theta$ whose sinus is $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$ and whose cosinus is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$ so you do have
$$\sin(\theta+x)=0\iff \theta+x=n\pi,\space n\in\mathbb Z$$